# Time Counter using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
function next_second(){
var target = '1350840000';    
var now = <?php echo time();?>;       
alert(now);
}
$(function() {
  setInterval(next_second, 1000);
});
```

the above alert function always returns same value. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: looks like set of requirements from a client..wait I thought its a question-answer help website from developers!!! popular response `WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED`

Comment: something is sadly wrong if you weren't able to turn up ANYTHING in a search for countdown timers

Comment: Please add some real code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is returning the same value is because the value of your 'now' variable is generated by the time your page loads. It doesn't make sense, because no matter how many times you execute the function, it would still return the same result/value.

You need to dynamically detect the current time but not on page load.

You can try the following script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function next_second(){
    var target = '1350840000';    
    var now = new Date().getTime();;       
    console.log(now);
}
$(function() {
  setInterval( next_second, 1000 );
});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP time is only set once (on page load) so it isn't updated at each interval. If you want to get the PHP (server) time on each interval, you will have to use ajax to grab it.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ for some examples.